# Android Studio 3.2 AAB Error : uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I updated to latest version of Android Studio i.e 3.2 I am able to build and generate apk.

But when I am trying to build aab I am getting below error:

> File 'root/lib/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.

Tried cleaning project & and also invalidate cache & restart